# how to let dummy variables show in one line

Tags: sql

My table is like this:

```
0    Number Certification
1    400009           CSR
2    400009            MD
3    400009           MHP
4    400032           CSP
5    400032           MH
```

After I use get dummies, then the table is like this:

```
 Number  Certification_ACD  ...  Certification_TSC  Certification_TSE
1    400009                  0  ...                  0                  0
2    400009                  0  ...                  0                  0
3    400009                  0  ...                  0                  0
```

I want the number column shows only once. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: How many certifications are there? If the number of them is known then a simple query can do the trick. It won't allow "dynamic" columns, though.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple python loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should serve your needs:

```sql
SELECT
    Number,
    SUM(Certification='ACD') AS Certification_ACD,
    SUM(Certification='TSC') AS Certification_TSC,
    SUM(Certification='TSE') AS Certification_TSE
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    Number
ORDER BY
    Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of them is known you can do:

```
select
  number,
  sum(case when certification = 'ACD' then 1 else 0 end) as cert_asd,
  sum(case when certification = 'TSC' then 1 else 0 end) as cert_tsc,
  sum(case when certification = 'TSE' then 1 else 0 end) as cert_tse,
  -- other cases here
from t
group by number
```

The `SUM()` function adds the certifications. If a person has the same certification multiple times, it will show `2`, or `3`, etc.